# Adding a sound affect to python code in VSC

Tags: python

I have been trying to add sound to my python code. I tried using playsound, pygame, pydub and tkinter but in vsc it doesn't let me install any using the command pip3 install pygame...(and so on)
here I have tried it with pydub but this sais that there is no module named pydub and it doesn't let me install it. Can someone help me add this sound to my code?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

psong = AudioSegment.from_mp3("song.mp3")
    play(song)
```

Comment: How are you installing modules? Have you verified that the Python environment that VSCode is using is the same environment you're installing to? As for how to check that, I suggest using Google, since it's a common issue.

Comment: I would recommend installing modules with your CMD prompt/Terminal instead of your VS Code Terminal, although realistically this should not matter, it might help in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions for this issue:

1. Install `pyaudio` (`pip3 install pyaudio`) as this is the best module that `pydub` uses.
2. Change your audio file format to `wav` instead of `mp3` and also change this section of code: `psong = AudioSegment.from_mp3("song.mp3")` to `psong = AudioSegment.from_wav("song.wav")`.

[Source for answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387571/playing-audio-in-pydub)